# Windows Batch File - Find and return string inside matching pattern

Tags: regex, batch-file, findstr

I'm using a batch file to identify and load fonts temporarily. It looks for strings like `/FontFamily(Rubber Dinghy Rapids)/` occurring inside .ai and .pdf files.

Now if I do `findstr /r FontFamily\(.*\) MyFile.ai`, this command returns a hugely interminable line of crap data with `FontFamily(Rubber Dinghy Rapids)` lost somewhere in there. I ACTUALLY need it to return the value of `.*` it found inside - in this case *Rubber Dinghy Rapids*.

Can I do this more elegantly? Or maybe I can switch to using VBScript if it's more elegant there?

My current solution is slow as hell... nested for loops, with one of them delimiting the crap data by the ( character, then finding the line that says `FontFamily(Rubber Dinghy Rapids` then stripping out the `FontFamily(` string, leaving me finally with *Rubber Dinghy Rapids*.

Comment: Two hints: (1) you use a greedy star match `.*` but you should use a lazy star match `.*?` instead. (2) To extract just the font family name, you need to use a **capture group**. I doubt that this two regex features are available in `findstr`. May be `grep` or a javascript regex can better suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an hybrid Batch-JScript program called FindRepl.bat that use JScript's regular expressions to search for strings in a file. Using my program you may solve your problem this way:

```
FindRepl.bat "FontFamily\((.*)\)" /$:1 < input.txt
```

You may get my program from [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697).